# bully can't work on mon0 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: linux, wifi

I'm running bully on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I got this output:

```
[!] Bully v1.0-22 - WPS vulnerability assessment utility
[!] ioctl(SIOCGIWFREQ) on 'mon0' failed with '-1221085440'
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

When I run `sudo airodump-ng mon0`, it works fine.

What does this error message mean?

Comment: first guess is negative one channel error

Comment: what is the solution

Comment: fix your wireless driver

Comment: how reinstall it